# Notification are not shown after application is closed

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I've got an older application (Let's simply call it A) and a newer application (let's call it B).

A has got repeating AlarmManager, which will launch code that displays notification with random text from app. It works without any problems even after you close app (by home button and back button  as well) or dismiss from recent apps list.

But then, there's app B. Main purpose of app B is displaying user some notification at given time. So once notification is planned, there's AlarmManager, which at given time displays notification. But there comes problem. What actually happens is, that most of the time B can display notifications, but when it's closed by back button, dismissed from recents apps list or when Android close it after certain time, AlarmManager calls BroadcastReceiver, which successfully calls IntentService (I know it because it also puts debug message to LogCat), but notification is not displayed and vibration is not launched.

**My question is:** What may be a cause for this problem? Or is there any way how to display notification even after app is not opened, but still running in background (I mean, if user force killed app, there's no reason to display notification, but when user just simply closed it in normal way, notification should be displayed)?

There's code of app A and B. Maybe you'll be able to find out why A workd and B not.

***APP A***

Setting AlarmIntent:

```
    alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);


    //Cancel previous alarm
    if(alarm != null){
        alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    //Setup alarm
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, DAY_IN_MILLIS, alarmIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

IntentService:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.random_text).toString())
        .setContentText(text)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_icon)
        .setLargeIcon( ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher) ).getBitmap() )
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));

    //Intent for activity
    Intent fullNotifIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.DISPLAY_TEXT");
    fullNotifIntent.putExtra("text", text);

    PendingIntent fullNotifPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, fullNotifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(fullNotifPendingIntent);


    //Display notification
    Notification notif = builder.build();
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notif);
```

***APP B***

Setting AlarmIntent:

```
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotifReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notifId", meta.notifId);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    //Cancel previous alarm
    if(alarm != null){
        alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, meta.getRemindTime(), alarmIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent receivedIntent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifService.class);
    long notifId= receivedIntent.getLongExtra("notifId", 0);
    intent.putExtra("notifId", notifId);
    context.startService(intent);

    Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "Broadcast received!");
}
```

IntentService:

```
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if(vibrator.hasVibrator()){
        long pattern[] = {0, 500, 250};
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 2);
    }


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(task.getName())
        .setContentText(task.getDescription())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notif)
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
        .setLights(config.getLedColor(), 2000, 2000);


    Notification notif = builder.build();
    android.app.NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Notify
    manager.notify(task.getNotifId(), notif);


    onLoadNextNotif();
    Log.d("serviceNotif", "done"); //This is successfully called even when displaying notification and vibrating fails
```

Comment: Put A's `Notification` logic into B. See if it works. If it does not, the problem is tied to something else in B, such as you blocked notifications for it in the device. If B does now work, though, slowly modify it to look more like B's current code, a line or so at a time, testing as you go, until you get to the point where you make the change that breaks B. It might be the lack of `setContentIntent()`, but that's just a guess.